# how to set Type face for web view in android

Tags: android, webview, typeface

Is it possible to set type face for android web view so that it support all the languages like gujarati, hindi, and tamil programacyically. Or is there any other way to get support for such languages on web view.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can load your font through javascript

Comment: Bipin thanks for your reply, can you tell me the procedure or send some examples so that I can go through it :). How to integrate java script.

Comment: Gujarati language is not supported in Google nexus(Kit kat) and in Lenovo tab. I am trying all these things for Google nexus and for Lenovo Tab but in samsung Gujarati is supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to inject Javascript in webview from tutorials and stackflow answers. Here is the tutorial that would be relevent.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-inject-javascript-into-an-android-web-view-for-a-more-dynamic-ux/

Once you know that you can use web fonts such as google fonts in your app. Here is how you can get started with google fonts.
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started

Comment: Bipin I tried the first link, Gujarati fonts are working in Samsung but in Google nexus(Kit kat) and Lenovo tab are not showing Gujarati fonts, instead these mobiles are showing square boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put your font in assets and load it in the local html like that

```
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
@font-face { font-family: MyCustomFont;  
src:url("~/android_asset/fonts/myfont.otf") } 
h2{ font-family: MyCustomFont; 
font-size:18; 
text-align: center;
line-height: normal;
margin:auto;
} 
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Appytech Arthur thanks for your reply. At the beginning only I tried whatever you said but no use :(. I am getting only square boxes.

Comment: square boxes means a problem with encoding. Have you tried to specify encoding in html like that 
`<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>`

or another encoding that would support the characters.

Also make sure you are saving your html file with UTF-8 encoding.
If you open your file with notepad you should see the correct characters, not square boxes. 
It worked for me in chinese